# How to create, install and import local typescript package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, package.json

I'm trying to make a package in typescript, [this](https://github.com/parascan-xyz/parascan-js/tree/f131b9959632ed41c97d071639571edd170f7302) one in particular. But after installing it locally in my project with `yarn add file:../parascan-js`, I can't import the modules correctly.

I expect import options for my package to be `parascan/components/*` (name changed from `uikit`) but what I see are the file/folders in the root such as src, dist, tsconfig etc. I want to be able to import with

```
import {Table} from "parascan/components/info"
```

Instead of this

```
import Table from "parascan/src/components/info/Table"
```

I've tried building dist folder with tsc and babel. Made some changes to package.json by adding `type: module` and `module: dist/index.js` but nothing worked.

Another way to look at this problem is using a generic common package like `@chakra-ui/react` as example. `Text` are imported with:

```
import { Text } from @chakra-ui/react
```

And not:

```
import { Text } from @chakra-ui/react/src/index
//or
//import { Text } from @chakra-ui/react/dist/index
```

I'm new to js/ts, so articles on how to create packages would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide one or many error messages. It doesnt work is not enough info for others to help you.

Comment: It's not error, but I'm not getting what I want. If I install generic packages from npm, e.g @chakra-ui/react, I could import a component with `import { Text } from @chakra-ui/react`. I want to be able to do that with my own package instead of just pointing to the particular file. I'm new to js/ts, so articles on how to create packages would be helpful. I thought I just have to export from index.ts and that's all.

Comment: that's already a lot more info! I suggest to adapt your question with these infos. Also, your link is broken.

Comment: I get that your trying, but your example isn't reproducible, it's probably a duplicate the way the question is worded, and you need to post the errors your getting _(aka **debugging details**)_. Remember many of these gals and guys are professional developers that are going to ask for professionalism.

Comment: Also share the package.json of the package you're including.